# electron-electron interactions in 1-D electron gas

Tags: condensed-matter, many-body, electronic-band-theory

The electron-electron interaction contribution to the hamiltonian in $k$-space representation is given by
$$\hat{V}_{ee}=\frac{1}{2L}\sum_{kk'q}V_{ee}(q)a^{\dagger}_{k-q}a^{\dagger}_{k'+q}a_{k'}a_{k}$$
In order to investigate the charge density excitation of the electron gas, the following operator is defined:
$$\hat{\rho}_{s,q}=\sum_{k}a^{\dagger}_{s,k+q}a_{s,k}$$
where $s$ labels the propagation direction of the mode:$s=+/-$ and correspondingly, we have $\bar{s}=-/+$.

Then, how can we show by using the definition of $\hat{\rho}$ that
$$\hat{V}_{ee}=\frac{1}{2L}\sum_{qs}(g_4\hat{\rho}_{s,q}\hat{\rho}_{s,-q}+g_2\hat{\rho}_{sq}\hat{\rho}_{\bar{s},-q})$$
where $g_2$ and $g_4$ are two constants measuring the strengh of the interaction at characteristic momenta $q=0$ and $q=2k_F$, respectively. The above result is taken from **B. Simons' condensed matter book**. I'm not able to arrive at this expression just by direction substitution of the defining form for $\hat{\rho}$ and the appearance of $\bar{s}$ in the expression seems to be quite peculiar.

Could anyone also explain the appearance of the two constants $g_2$ and $g_4$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Attach the indices $s = L/R$ explicitly to $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$, and then consider different cases: forward scattering, backward scattering (and Umklapp scattering).

Comment: @L.Su I will treat you some junk food someday

Comment: @L.Su again about the 1-D electron gas, shouldn't the non-interacting part of the hamiltonian be $\hat{H}_0=-\sum_{s=R,L}\sum_q{a^{\dagger}_{sq}\sigma_sv_Fqa_{sq}+E_F}$?

Comment: @L.Su the expression given in the book seems to be the part that is relative to the fermi energy, otherwise it doesn't make sense to have some cutoff for $q$.

Comment: Yes. Very likely. You are TIM?

Comment: @L.Su OMG, what do you think, my majesty the king of junk food